# How to solve Access denied for user 'root'@ when connect Laravel with mysql through docker

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker, docker-compose

Im trying to deploy my laravel app using docker. Then I created docker-compose.yml file and Dockerfile like below.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    app:
        build:
            args:
                user: sammy
                uid: 1000
            context: ./
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: travellist
        container_name: travellist-app
        restart: unless-stopped
        working_dir: /var/www/
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        networks:
            - travellist

    db:
        image: 'mysql:latest'
        restart: 'unless-stopped'
        ports:
            - '3306:3306'
        environment:
            - 'MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=true'
            - 'MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}'
            - 'MYSQL_USER=${DB_USER}'
            - 'MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}'
            - 'MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true'
        volumes:
            - 'laravel-database:/var/lib/mysql/'
        networks:
            - 'travellist'

    nginx:
        image: nginx:alpine
        container_name: travellist-nginx
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - 8000:80
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - ./docker-compose/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
        networks:
            - travellist

networks:
    travellist:
        driver: bridge

volumes:
    laravel-database:
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Arguments defined in docker-compose.yml
ARG user
ARG uid

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd

# Get latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Create system user to run Composer and Artisan Commands
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && \
    chown -R $user:$user /home/$user

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

USER $user
```

And when I try docker-compose up, all the containers run with a any error. And also when I run docker-compose ps, it shows like this,

```
      Name                    Command               State                          Ports
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
proj_db_1          docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up      0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp,:::3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
travellist-app     docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm    Up      9000/tcp
travellist-nginx   /docker-entrypoint.sh ngin ...   Up      0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp,:::8000->80/tcp
```

But, when laravel application, tries to connect with mysql, it doesnt happens. And even I cant connect using TablePlus, it shows this.

```
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 10060
```

And laravel application shows this below error..

```
local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'172.19.0.3' (using password: YES)
```

Here is my .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=here_goes_db_name
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=tyutyu
```

How can I fix and connect my laravel application and mysql ?? And also how can I log into table plus ??

Answer (score 0):

First, you can try to connect to the database with database tools, such as Navicat, Dbforge.

Secondly, if I can't connect to the database tool, it may be that the host,username,password of your database connection is not correct, then it has nothing to do with laravel, you need to find the problem from the docker configuration itself.

Third, if the database can be connected, then laravel is also sure to be connected, which will need to find laravel's database configuration to see if there is any error.

Comment: I tried to hard code all the db credentials in the docker-compose.yml file.. But, still gives me this error.. Is there a way to fix this ??

Comment: You can just set the database account and password directly, don't use random passwords. I suggest removing this configuration from compose  environment:
            - 'MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=true'.  Or try to write the database account password directly under the compose file, not in the dockerfile. @Amithash